# how to create a button that opens a popup without automatic registration / creation of the form odoo13

Tags: button, widget, odoo, wizard, autosave

I want to create a button that opens a popup that takes over some form fields.
These fields can be modified / filled in.
When closing the fields concerned are updated.
without saving or creating the record before I click on the save button.
I don't see how to get there knowing that there are no relational fields.
Should I create a widget, a wizard, both ....
Help me please.

Here is my current code :

**test_scale.py :**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import models, fields, api


class TestScale(models.Model):
    _name = 'test.scale'

    name = fields.Char(required=True)
    weighing = fields.Integer('weighing', default=0)
```

**test_scale.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <record id="test_scale_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">test.scale.tree</field>
        <field name="model">test.scale</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Test scale">
                <field name="name"></field>
                <field name="weighing"></field>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="test_scale_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">test.scale.form</field>
        <field name="model">test.scale</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Test scale">
                <sheet>
                    <group name="main_info">
                        <field name="name"></field>
                        <field name="weighing"></field>
                        <button name="%(test_scale_configurator_action)d"
                                type="action"
                                string="Weighing"
                                class="oe_highlight"
                                context="{'weighing': weighing}"></button>
                    </group>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>


    <record id="saisie_menu_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Test_scale</field>
        <field name="res_model">test.scale</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
            <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Aucun enregistrement
            </p>
        </field>
    </record>


    <menuitem id="test_scale_menu"
              name="Test_scale"/>

    <menuitem id="test_scale_saisie_menu"
              parent="test_scale_menu"
              name="Saisie"
              action="saisie_menu_action"/>
</odoo>
```

**test_scale_configurator.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="test_scale_configurator_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">test.scale.configurator.view.form</field>
        <field name="model">test.scale.configurator</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form>
                <field name="weighing"/>
                <footer>
                    <button type="object"
                            name="button_save"
                            string="Save"
                    />
                    <button special="cancel"
                            string="Cancel"
                            class="btn-secondary"/>
                </footer>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="test_scale_configurator_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Test Scale</field>
        <field name="res_model">test.scale.configurator</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="target">new</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="test_scale_configurator_view_form"/>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

**test_scale_configurator.py :**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields


class TestScaleConfigurator(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'test.scale.configurator'

    weighing = fields.Integer(string='weighing')

    def button_save(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

This thing is done by relational fields of odoo , For EX:-

In your `test.scale` model your field is `weighing`,

First you need to configure your current model `test.scale` 's id in wizard so you can reference it, like this you can add the field in wizard.

```
test_scale_id = fields.Many2one(string="Test Scale")
```

After that add `context` in you main model's xml file where is the button which one opens the wizard like this.

```
<button name="%(test_scale_configurator_action)d"
                            type="action"
                            string="Weighing"
                            class="oe_highlight"
                            context="{'default_test_scale_id': active_id}"></button>
```

After that this field needs to be invisible in your wizard's form in order to save data in wizard so you can refernce it later.

```
<field name="test_scale_id" invisible="1"/>
```

and in your wizard weighing field is stayed like this.

```
weighing = fields.Integer(string='weighing', related='test_scale_id.weighing', readonly=False)
```

**Note: This process , making field is one time process.**

after that you can use any field which is in your main model and you want to use in wizard you can get those fields by `test_scale_id.any_of_your_field`.

Comment: Hello.
thank you for your answer.
I have made the changes you proposed.
But when I click on the button that brings up the wizard,
the form is automatically saved although the user has not clicked on save.
I would like the form to save only when the user clicks on save.

Comment: Ok so add readonly=False in wizard file, I am editing my answer please check.

Comment: Okay.
The wizard is called by clicking a button which automatically saves my form as if I had clicked on save. But I don't want it to save my form when I click the "weighing" button. And even with your modifications it does.
Do I have to go through a widget? If so how can I connect a widget button to my formulair.xml and how can this widget button call a python method?